# How do I make ssd the bootable drive ubuntu?

Tags: boot, system-installation, ssd, configuration

I installed the new SSD in the second bay of my HP dv7-1133cl and put a fresh install of ubuntu on it with a usb flash drive, then changed the boot order back to normal afterward. However, the computer doesn't recognize the SSD as a bootable dirive, and boots only to the original hard drive. I know the system sees the SSD, and I can even look at all the OS files on it (when booted to the HDD), but it won't boot the SSD. I don't have the option to select the SSD as the first to boot in my version of BIOS. If I take the HDD out of the laptop and only put the SSD in, the computer tells me to load a bootable drive. In that case, I never get to grub or anywhere at all. What do I need to do to make the SSD bootable?

Comment: i don't know how you can boot ssd outside of bios setting, but you could always have your install run from ssd, but have your grub [boot-loader] boot your system from the  hdd your bios allows.

Comment: What kind of interface does the SSD use? USB, M.2, SATA?

Comment: It might be a PCI-E SSD which old BIOS do not support. In that case you could just use your HDD to boot from grub.

Comment: the ssd is SATA interface. the laptop uses BIOS (it's almost 10 years old now). Is there a way to find out if I need to initialize this SSD with another computer?

Comment: Also, I tried partitioning grub2 on to the very front of the hard drive, and everything else on the SSD. It caused a fatal error while installing grub2, so I had to install both the boot partition and grub2 on the hdd, everything else on the ssd. My boot time has actually gotten LONGER now (was about 52 seconds, now it's 65 seconds). Everything else is very fast, as expected... I just wish I could boot from the SSD. Is there a way to have only grub2 on the hdd and keep the boot partition on the ssd?

Comment: Last note; I did one last re-install of Ubuntu, and left a small, unmounted ext4 partition at the front of the SSD drive (just in case it's possible to create /boot files and make it the bootable drive). Other than (hopefully) finding a way to do this, I'm done doing any more partitioning/life-sucking on these disks for a good while. Oddly enough, it now loads in 30 seconds, and I imagine much of that is boot-loading on the hdd.

Comment: If you boot from the HDD and from Terminal run `sudo update-grub` it should add the SSD install of Ubuntu to the boot loader.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late reply, but I just wondered if you've tried updating the BIOS for your specific laptop, maybe that way it will recognize your new SSDas a bootable option?

Not at all a tech-savvy guy, just thinking out a not so farfetched solution.

I leave you the URL for hp BIOS update
https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c00042629

Let us know if it worked or if you worked it out other way.